# Swiper sample does not work with Next 13 out of the box

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

Swiper does not work with Next 13. The default React example of Swiper + `'use client'` at the top of the page does not work.

Steps to reproduce:

- Use this command to create a bare-bone Next 13 app:
- `npx --yes create-next-app next --use-npm --js --eslint --no-src-dir --experimental-app --import-alias @/*`
- Then remove the global style from `layout.js`.
- Then replace the entire `page.js` content with Swiper's default example for react.
- Add `'use client'` to the top of `page.js`
- Now run using `npm run dev`.
- You should see that slides are stacked one above the other.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I followed the steps and used [react default demo](https://swiperjs.com/demos#default) and it seems its not broken and works. I copied the `styles.css` file as well.

Comment: @c0m1t as I said, it does not work in Next 13.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is solved by changing:

`import "swiper/css";`
to
`import "swiper/swiper.min.css";`

[Next 13.3.0] [App Directory] ['use client']